Cannot connect to Cassandra from Python script
I am facing a issue connecting to cassandra db using python. for connecting I have 4 host to connect, cluster credential and cluster ssl which consist of truststore file which is in jks format and password for that file. I am able to connect using datastax. this is provided by my company. But I need to connect using python script. I have tried converting the jks file to .pem file but getting the timeout error. I have tried all the solution which were available online but none of it work. Is there some simple approach to it.
Note: there is no private key file just one jks file and inside that file also there is no private key.
I have tried all the solution which were available, like converting the jks file to pem file.

$ keytool -list -v -keystore truststore.jks

$ keytool -export -alias <alias> -file cert.pem -keystore truststore.jks


$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore truststore.jks -srcstoretype jks -destkeystore truststore.p12 -deststoretype pkcs12 -srcalias <alias> -deststorepass password


$ openssl pkcs12 -in truststore.p12 -cacerts -out truststore.pem -nokeys


You didn't provide enough details in your question so as a general guidance, you will need to install the Python driver for Apache Cassandra so you can write Python applications with Cassandra as the database backend:
$ pip install cassandra-driver

If you are already using the Python driver but just need guidance for configuring SSL, see the Cassandra Python driver Security documentation for examples.
As a side note, you will get a better response if you provide the right details when asking a question. You should include things like (a) a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem. For guidance, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/tour and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Cheers!
